# MobaXterm Newline

Tags: mobaxterm

Is there any way to set MobaXterm to implicitly add Carriage Return chars (`"\r"`) when a Newline character, `"\n"`, is received?  Like in TeraTerm you can set NewLine to CR, CR+LF, LF or auto.

[image: No carriage return with new line]

Comment: I'm confused by use of 'implicit' here. Do you want the cursor to move to the first column -- perform the carriage return action -- when LF is received? ... now that I ask that I have vague memories from lifetimes ago about this term being used in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the terminal screen, select "Change terminal settings..." and check "Implicit CR in every LF"

Comment: Absolutely nothing happens if I right-click on the terminal in MobaxTerm.  Moreover, nowhere do I find *Implicit CR in every LF* in the Terminal Settings.

Comment: it works. just change terminal settings not saved when you start another session.

Comment: If no context menu, then either press shift while right-click or disable config setting "paste on right-click"

Comment: FWIW "Implicit CR in every LF" is confusing. Makes no sense to include a byte in a byte. Maybe "on every" or even better "after each" is closer to what they mean. And what does 'implicit' mean? Does that mean the display/output will act as if the input stream has a CR after LF? I guess that's implicit WRT the stream, but it's explicit WRT the display. Confusing.

Answer (score 1):

shift right click if answer of Denis pops no options menu

Comment: Who knew!!  Thank you - that solved my question!

Comment: FYI: if the config setting 'paste on right-click' is enabled, you have to use shift to get the context menu to open ... terrible UX IMO.